# nativescript 'tns run android' throws ClassNotFoundException

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I did a fresh clone of the nativescript grocery git repo, and checked out the angualr-start branch, did 'platform add android', and then 'tns run android' (which my android device connected)
The app came up and displayed this error: pastebin.com/1YbThGkZ

perhaps the most significant part of the error being this:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.tns.FragmentClass" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/org.nativescript.groceries-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/org.nativescript.groceries-1/lib/arm, /data/app/org.nativescript.groceries-1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /vendor/lib, /systementer code here/lib]]
```

Solution: upgrade to native script (and tns-core-modules) v2.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

upgrade to native script (and tns-core-modules) v2.1

```
sudo npm install nativescript -g --unsafe-perm
tns plugin remove tns-core-modules
tns plugin add tns-core modules
```